# history.js - initial page not being stored in history

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the history.js to enable back/forward browser navigation on an AJAX products page. The AJAX functionality is based on clicking on product categories.

I have this working quite well - except there is one issue I am experiencing. The very first page is not being stored in the history. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<ul class="category">
    <li><a href="/category/5">Category 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="/category/10">Category 10</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var
        History = window.History,
        State = History.getState();

    $('.category a').click(function(){

        var path = $(this).attr('href');
        var title = $(this).next().text();
        var category = $(this).attr('data-cat');

        History.pushState({category: category}, title, path);

        return false;
    });

});


History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function() {
    var State = History.getState();
    var category = State.data.category;

    myAjaxFunction(category); // function which refreshes the product container
});
```

Now suppose I load up URL: //mysite/category/10

I then click on Category 5 - I get URL: //mysite/category/5

I then click on the Back button - the URL does not change and the AJAX function brings back incorrect resultset

I did a console.log and it tells me that "State.data.category" is undefined.

It looks like the initial page isn't being stored in the history session and I have tried forcing a History.pushState on page load but this means that the 'statechange' event gets triggered on page load too, which is unnecessary.

Has anyone got any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can to call *statechange* event by jQuery into the:

> ```
> $(document).ready(function(){ 
>
>     ...
>
>     jQuery(window).trigger('statechange');
>
> });
> ```